# WPF layout and event routing (hit test) - how do I construct my hierarchy?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am trying to wrap my head around the following problem:
I have a Grid with 3 rows, 1 column. Each of the cells have some sub controls. Additionally, I have on control which spans the entire 3 rows, something like an "overlay" where I render some visuals across the entire Grid. I need hit testing on this overlay as well as on the sub controls. 
However, due to how the logical/visual tree is constructed, the parent of the overlay is the Grid and not its children (which are on the same level in the tree as the overlay).
How could I construct the WPF tree, so that the events bubble up to the other controls of the Grid.

The tree looks something like this:

```
Grid
  - Row 1 Control
  - Row 2 Control
  - Row 3 Control
  - Overlay (Row 1 - 3) Control
```

If the overlay does not handle an event, I need to handle it in the Row 1/2/3 controls. I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at WPF's support for [hittesting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx) using [`VisualTreeHelper.HitTest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608753.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but I think I would still need a visual tree first, which correctly represents my problem. When using the VisualTreeHelper.HitTest method with the overlay node and nothing is hit, the other 3 controls (row 1 - 3) would not get tested.

Comment: If you use VisualTreeHelper.HitTest with your Grid as starting reference, the HitTest method will test for all children of the Grid including the Overlay control and the other three controls.  This is described in the section "How the Visual Tree Affects Hit Testing" in the link I provided.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that. How would you deal with other events?

Comment: I'm not sure which events you mean?

Comment: For example, one of the controls could be a button and if nothing in the overlay is hit, I would like all the button events to be fired as if they overlay was not there.

Comment: I doubt that you can do all this automatically.  I think you'd have to do the hittesting yourself and then fire the click events manually for the buttons.  Here is one way of doing that: http://www.nivisec.com/2008/08/click-wpf-button-in-code.html